# Export and upload a key from Java keystore shows different instruction for different account

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, android-keystore

I have multiple google play store account. While uploading new app, I choose "Opt in to Play App Signing" and select "Export and upload a key from Java keystore" option. So far, I have seen below instruction for this option,

[image]

However, recently I see another instruction where it says to output a "output.zip" file with additional `--include-cert` argument to the command.

[image]

I want to know what is difference between these two instruction. I couldn't find anything in the internet or Stackoverflow about this. Would be great, if someone can shed some light on this. Thanks!